# CKEditor stopped working after adding JSON to my MVC intranet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, model-view-controller, ckeditor, datatables

I have a intranet website where I have a page to add new products.

I use ckeditor because I need to save some links.

Now I had to change it into a Master detail form and so I decided to use Json2 and DataTables .

The strangest thing is that when I include

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript">
```

the ckeditor doesn't work anymore.

These are all the scripts I import

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@*This is for CKEditor*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/content/javascript/CKEditor/ckeditor.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/content/javascript/CKEditor/adapters/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>

@*This is for jquery*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@*This is for JSON*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@*These are for DataTables*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js")"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js")"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

@*These are for styling Control*@
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools.css")"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css")"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the reference to jquery before you add ckeditor.  The adaptors are set to extend jquery.

Comment: i've done much worse myself.  would you do the honour of accepting this as the answer?

Comment: I would, I just need to wait 20m before I can do it.